# What does it mean "the function will find and store in a parameter, the sum of two other parameters?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, reference

There is a function called `findSumProd(int alpha, int beta, int& gamma, int& delta)`.
How would I create a function that will find and store in the third parameter *gamma*, the sum of *alpha* and *beta*?

I am new at C++ so please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Mostly in jest: the letter sigma ∑ is used for sums; presumably, `delta` ∆ is for the difference between `alpha` and `beta`?  If you don't have to do something with `delta`, then there are too many parameters to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assign the sum of alpha and beta to gamma. For example

```
#include <iostream>

void findSumProd(int alpha, int beta, int& gamma, int& delta)
{
   // some calculations with alpha and betta

   gamma = alpha + beta;
}

int main()
{
   int alpha, beta, gamma, delta;

   // some calculations with these variable

   findSumProd( alpha, beta, gamma, delta );

   std::cout << "gamma = " << gamma << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Can you also explain to me how two variables, called numb1 and numb2, will be recieved as parameters plus two other parameters, and the last two parameters would be used to return the sum and the product, and the main program would store the sum and prod into "theSum" and "theProduct"?

Comment: Call the function the following way findSumProd( numb1, numb2, theSum, theProduct );

Answer (score 1):

It means if I write something like this

```
int c, d;
findSumProd(1, 2, c, d);
printf("%d\n", c);
```

I will get 3.

For how to implement it, go to Google and search for `pass by reference C++`

Answer (score 0):

`gamma` is a reference. That means when you call `findSumProd(a, b, g, d)`, the variables `g` and `d` can be altered from within `findSumProd`. `gamma` and `delta` *refer* to `g` and `d`.

In your function you can write something like `gamma = /*...*/;`

Comment: So if I write: int alpha=0; int beta=0; then gamma = alpha + beta; would that means that I stored the sum of alpha and beta into the third parameter of gamma?